# Apply a plugin only when DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following statement that applies a jQuery plugin to a DOM element (scrollbar plugin)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pp-meta-content").customScrollbar();
    });
</script>
```

As you can see it checks if the Document is ready and then changes the DOM element given through selector.

It works, but not when the DOM is loaded later by another element or when DOM is hidden(). Do you know a way for an event to wait when the DOM is shown or displayed and then execute something....?

Someting like this:

```
$(element).on("show", function(){

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"not when the DOM is loaded later by another element or when DOM is hidden()"_?

Comment: Just call a function when you `show()` the element?

Comment: I think he's asking how to apply a plugin to a dynamically-added element.

Comment: yes that's my question @Bermar

Comment: Could be usefull to have some of the code that add the said element and/or display the DOM

Answer (score 3):

If you load an element later, you need to wait until then to apply the plugin to it. E.g. if you load it with AJAX, apply it in the callback function:

```
$("#somediv").load("someurl.php", function() {
    $("#somediv .pp-meta-content").customScrollbar();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `show` callback. It will get called after the element is shown.

```
$(element).show('fast', function() {/* insert plugin code */});
```